# How to start apcupsd at boot?

Tags: power-management, startup, mint

This should be simple, but I am stuck figuring it out.

I am using `apcupsd` to manage my system in case of power outage.

I know how to start the server: `sudo /etc/apcupsd/apcupsd start` (See the manual [here](http://www.apcupsd.org/manual/manual.html).)

But how do I make `apcupsd` run at boot on an Ubuntu system?

Comment: Did you install it straightforwardly just with apt? I did it that way and whatever magic is required to start it automatically was done for me.

Answer (score 0):

The installation script should have handled this for you. If you are on GUI, you can confirm by checking for apcupsd in the list of startup applications:

**System > Preferences > Startup Applications**

If this is not the case or doesn't apply, these further resources can assist:

- [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)
- [Run a program on startup using Ubuntu | Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/run-a-program-startup-using-ubuntu-2205696)